# I am unable to create users in the identitystore API from the boto3 library for AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I get this error ""errorMessage": "'IdentityStore' object has no attribute 'create_user'" when I try to use the create_user method from the boto3 library for identitystore. The link to the boto3 class:https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/identitystore.html.

This is my code snippet for the command:

```
response = boto3.client('identitystore').create_user(
                  IdentityStoreId='******',
                  UserName= ****,
                  DisplayName= ****
                  )
```

The info is blurred out.

I heard that identitystore is the successor of the AWS signle sign on but I am not sure whether the error is due to that.

I am hoping to add users from a dynamboDB table to the identity store.

Comment: You may be using old boto3 version. Make sure you use the latest one.

Comment: How do I use the new boto3 version? Is there a link with the new boto3 version?